# Multiple interviews with the same company?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, recruitment, hiring-process, human-resources

I’ve been really wanting to be part of this organization. And I just interviewed with a recruiter last week for one of the locations about an hour away from me and over the weekend I applied to a few of their other locations - 2 out of state. Now 3 of the locations I’ve applied for over the weekend set up a phone interview with me.

So far it’s a total of 4 interviews with 4 different recruiters. 2 out of state. I don’t mind going out of state if the opportunity is right. Do you think all 4 recruiters will speak with each other? Or not because they’re in totally different region?  Have you been in this situation before? I was thinking of mentioning it only if they bring it up?

Comment: I really doubt they speak to each other, but I wouldn't be surprised if your full name appeared multiple times in their database. Technically, you're not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know for sure that these jobs are for same positions from the same (geographically distributed) team - it's ok to apply for multiple positions. Based on your preference and their acceptance, you can choose any one, if you land on multiple offers. Usually the pay-scale can vary based on location - so I do not see any downside for these applications.

Answer (score 1):

The recruiters are not likely to speak to each other, but of course it can happen. It is not a bad thing to do, but make sure to mention it when they ask if you have other ongoing applications. Being secretive about this will turn out bad, and there is no reason to. Just make sure you are honest/consistent in what you tell them during the different interviews. You don't want to be caught while providing answers that contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that technically you're not doing anything wrong by applying to multiple positions. However what I get from your question is that you're worried you fail one job interview, and that same recruiter inform the others that you failed and they decide not to pursue it any further.

No way for us to know for sure but it is possible that if the interview go very wrong, they might put you on the "do not hire" list. But I very much doubt that based on your question. I should also mention that if the jobs are different, then the qualification might be different. So you might fail one criteria but not on the other job description.

Personally I would just continue to apply until you get an offer. At that time, you might disclose that you have other applications if they are still pending but I just wouldn't bring them up at all since it might confuse them.